# Does there exist a nontrivial rational function which satisfies $f(f(f(f(x))))=x$?

Tags: functional-equations, rational-functions

It's pretty well known and easy to show that for a linear fractional function $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ to be an involution, ie. $f(f(x))=x$, then $a\cdot d=-1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

An example of a rational function which satisfies $f(f(f(x)))=x$ is $\frac{x-1}{x}$.

I was fooling around with a few of these types of questions with a friend, and we got stuck on $f(f(f(f(x))))=x$. Does there exist a solution $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ where $g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $f(f(x))\neq x$.

So far we've discovered that $f$ is bijective, $F(x):=f(f(x))$ is an involution, and $f(x)=\frac{1+ix}{x+i}$ works if we loosen the requirement on integer/rational coefficients, as $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}$ in this case.

We highly suspect that if $g(x), h(x)$ exist, then they are degree 3 or above as $F(F(x))=\frac{ax+b}{cx-a}$ doesn't seem to be yielding any acceptable solutions (and degree 2 doesn't satisfy bijectivity).

Comment: `if we loosen the requirement on integer/rational coefficients` Then $\,f(x)=i x\,$ suffices.

Comment: true... good point haha

Comment: I'm just curious, but wouldn't any self-inverse function do?  if $f = f^{-1}$, then $f(f(f(f(x)))) = x$ always, doesn't it?  Unless, do you mean that "nontrivial" means "not linear in both numerator and denominator"?

Comment: I had $f(f(x))\neq x$ in my post, which is equivalent to $f=f^{-1}$. Because yes you are correct every function where $f^{(2)}(x)=x$ automatically satisfies $f^{(4)}(x)=x$.

Comment: Ah, yes apologies, I see it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is a Mobius transform of order $n> 1$.

Since we are in characteristic zero, $f$ can't be conjugate to a translation, and since $n > 1$ it can't be the identity, so $f$ must have two distinct fixed points in $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$, and then the derivative of $f$ at those fixed points must be a primitive $n$th root of unity.

Moreover, the product of those derivative is always $1$, so the sum of the two derivatives has to be $2\cos(2k\pi/n)$ where $k$ is coprime with $n$ (this is in fact equivalent to $f$ having order $n$).

But, the sum of the derivatives at the fixed points is a rational expression in terms of the coefficients of the Mobius transform (it is a pretty big one, you should convince yourself this works because it is a symmetric algebraic expression in terms of the two fixed points, and those fixed points satisfy a degree $2$ equation whose coefficients are expressions in terms of the coefficients of $f$)

So if such an $f$ exists with coefficients in $K$, you must have $2\cos(2\pi/n) \in K$. If $K = \Bbb Q$ this implies $\Bbb Q(2\cos(2\pi/n)) = \Bbb Q$. Looking at the degree of those extensions you get $\phi(n) = 1$ or $2$, so $n=2,3$ or $4$

---

To make a suitable Mobius transform of order $4$, take for example the one whose fixed points are at $\pm i$ and where the derivative are $\pm i$ there.

Then letting $g(z) = (z-i)/(z+i)$, we must have that $g(f(g^{-1}))(z) = iz$ (after conjugating by $g$, its fixed points are $0$ and $\infty$ so it is a scaling).

Thus $f(z) = g^{-1}(ig(z)) = (1+z)/(1-z)$

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So if I follow correctly, there is no homography of order n>4? It'll take me a while to digest your post, I admit its been a while since I've done much theory with homographies. I'm not sure how to generalize to (odd, say) rational functions with numerator/denominator degree more than 1, in hopes of finding $f$ with order >4.

Comment: If $f$ has a numerator or denominator of larger degree $d$ and it doesn't cancel with the denominator or numerator, then it has degree $d> 1$, and then $f^{\circ n}$ has degree $dn$ so it can't be the identity.
(you can think of the degree as algebraic as the degree of the extension $K(f(z)) \subset K(z)$ or as the topological degree, it is the same thing)

Comment: You can have homographies of higher order but they will need to have coefficients that are a bit more complicated. For example if $n=5$ you need to take coefficients in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5))$. Anyway, the space of homographies is a space of dimension $3$. Usually you can parametrize them with the image of $3$ points, or with the coefficients after setting one of them to $1$, but for dynamical purposes it is often helpful to think of homographies as a pair of fixed points and a derivative at one of them.

Comment: I'm creating math questions for a high school tournament, so I suppose n=4 is as high as I can go to not scare them away haha. Thanks for all your help the responses have been great :)

Answer (score 10):

Consider the following

$$f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
$$\implies ff(x)=-\frac 1x$$
$$\implies fff(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$
$$\implies ffff(x)=x$$

Postscript...
I was thinking along the lines of $$f(x)=\tan(\arctan x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$

It is easily verified that this is the same function as I have given above.

Furthermore we can fairly easily check that if $$f(x)=\tan(\arctan x+\frac{\pi}{3})$$ then $$fff(x)=x$$ although this function does not fit the requirements.

Therefore consider the function $$f(x)=\tan(\arctan x+\frac{\pi}{n})$$ where $n$ is prime. We can postulate that $$f^{(n)}(x)=x$$ but such a function would also not satisfy the requirements.

The only reason why this works "nicely" for $n=4$ is because $\tan\frac{\pi}{4}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: oh, brilliant! How did you find this solution, just trial/error with $ff(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$? As a followup, can you generalize your technique to $f^{(p)}(x)=x$? ($f$ composed with itself $p$ times for p-prime)

Comment: Please see my postscript

Answer (score 2):

Since every [Moebius Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
is associated to an invertible matrix
$$
f(z) = {{az + b} \over {cz + d}}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad H = \left( {\matrix{
   a & b  \cr 
   c & d  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
and the convolution of two Transformations is associated to the 
product of the associated matrices
$$
f_{\,2}  \circ f_{\,1} \quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad H_{\,2} \;H_{\,1} 
$$
then
$$
f \circ f \circ f \circ f = id\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad H^{\,4}  = I
$$
corresponds to find the $4$-th roots of the Identity matrix.

Standing the above, as the "basic" fourth roots we can take:
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right),\;\;\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & { - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right),\;\;\,\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & i  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
noting that the $1$st is the square of the $2$nd, which in turn is the square of the $3$rd.
So, only for the $3$rd the square is different from $I$.

Also, it is to be noted that the rotation matrix
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \left( {\pi /2} \right)} & { - \sin \left( {\pi /2} \right)}  \cr 
   {\sin \left( {\pi /2} \right)} & {\cos \left( {\pi /2} \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right) \equiv  - i\,\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & i  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
can be derived from the third, so in case we can replace one for the other.

As rightly underlined by *Quasicoherent*, the correspondence $f \Rightarrow H$ is net of a common factor,
so that at the end we shall write
$$
H^{\,4}  = I\quad  \Rightarrow \quad f 
 = {{\lambda \,h_{\,1,1} \,z + \lambda \,h_{\,1,2} } \over {\lambda \,h_{\,2,1} \,z + \lambda \,h_{\,2,2} }}\quad \left| {\;\lambda  \in \mathbb C} \right.
$$

Comment: One small problem with this is that the group of Möbius transformations is actually isomorphic to $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, which ignores scalar matrices. For instance both $I$ and $-I$ correspond to the identity map $f(z) = z$. So actually $f^{\circ 4} = \mathrm{id} \iff H^4 = \lambda I$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. One small thing, your example matrix H also satisfies $H^2=\pm I$ which implies $f(f(x))=x$ as well.

Comment: @Quasicoherent: you are right, thanks for signalling: I amended my answer.

Comment: @user2615107: well the example I put before was not exhaustive. I corrected my answer to include all the roots, dividing into those which derive from $I$, from its square root, and "pure" fourth root.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \frac{Ax + B}{Cx + D}$$
$$f^4(x) = x$$
$$\bigg(Cx^2 + (D - A)x - B\bigg)\bigg(A + D\bigg)\bigg(A^2 + 2BC + D^2\bigg) = 0$$

The solution where $A = 1, B = 1, C = -1, D = 1$ is one case of $A^2 + 2BC + D^2 = 0$.  But you could also do $A = -D$ .

$Cx^2 + (D - A)x - B = 0$ is the special case of $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if $f(g(x))=x$, where both $f$, $g$ are rational functions, then both $f$, $g$ must be quotients of polynomials of degree $\le 1$.